# Qt button take as much space as the text on it needs

Tags: qt, layout, pyqt, qt-designer

I have a button in Qt Designer and I want it to take always as much space as the text on it needs. How can i accomplish that?

I mean like the text on the button is "Hello" and the button will be 45px.

When I do `self.button.setText("Hello World")` the button will be 85px.

My current "servers.ui":

```
<item>
<widget class="QPushButton" name="pageLabel">
 <property name="sizePolicy">
  <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Preferred">
   <horstretch>0</horstretch>
   <verstretch>0</verstretch>
  </sizepolicy>
 </property>
 <property name="maximumSize">
  <size>
   <width>40</width>
   <height>16777215</height>
  </size>
 </property>
 <property name="text">
  <string/>
 </property>
 <property name="flat">
  <bool>true</bool>
 </property>
</widget>
</item>
```

I'm actually talking about:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6tqe.png]

Comment: Try calling updateGeometry http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#updateGeometry after changing the text

Comment: Like this https://i.imgur.com/S5N1JN0.png ? It's still cut off.

Comment: Settings in Designer: https://i.imgur.com/A5nqzlK.png

Comment: @Chris Please take a look above ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `QToolButton` instead of a `QPushButton` and clear its maximum size.

You may need to set the vertical size-policy to "Preferred" so that it to has the same height as the other buttons. To get a flat button, check the  "autoRaise" property.

A quick way to change the button class is to right-click it and select "Morph Into" from the context menu.

Comment: I had to set the horizontal size policy to maximum but besides that; https://i.imgur.com/XXy7D3y.png